# Why queries are getting progressively slower when using postgres with spring batch?

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-batch, hikaricp

I'm running a job using Spring Batch 4.2.0 with postgres (11.2) as backend. It's all wrapped in a spring boot app. I've 5 steps and each runs using a simple partitioning strategy to divide data by id ranges and reads data into each partition (which are processed by separate threads). I've about 18M rows in the table, each step reads, changes few fields and writes back. Each step reads all 18M rows and writes back. The issue I'm facing is, the queries that run to pull data into each thread scans data by id range like,

`select field_1, field_2, field_66 from table where id >= 1 and id < 10000`.

In this case each thread processes 10_000 rows at a time. When there's no traffic the query takes less than a second to read all 10,000 rows. But when the job runs there's about 70 threads reading all that data in. It goes progressively slower to almost a minute and a half, any ideas where to start troubleshooting this?

I do see autovacuum running in the backgroun for almost the whole duration of job. It definitely has enough memory to hold all that data in memory (about 6GB max heap). Postgres has sufficient shared_buffers 2GB, max_wal_size 2GB but not sure if that in itself is sufficient. Another thing I see is loads of `COMMIT` queries hanging around when checking through `pg_stat_activity`. Usually as much as number of partitions. So, instead of 70 connections being used by 70 partitions there are 140 conections used up with 70 of them running `COMMIT`. As time progresses these `COMMIT`s get progressively slower too.

Comment: I can't see from what you shared the reason for that. Are you passing data between steps through the execution context? Can you share a minimal config to illustrate your setup?

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine Yes I'm. I've a partitioner that checks max and min of ids from db and puts them in context. And each partition picks one of these max and mins and runs rest of step. The reader is stepscoped to get hold of the max and min in context. I'll try and see if I can reproduce with fewer rows..

Answer (score 0):

You are probably hitting https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/3634.

This issue has been fixed and will be part of version 4.2.3 planned to be released this week.

Comment: Interesting thanks - but I'm not sure if I'm hitting this issue (yet!) as I cannot see the problem query running when I look at what queries postgres itself is running when things are getting slower. Am I missing something?